# CSS background property usage

Tags: html, css, syntax, properties, background

Recently I saw a tutorial on how to convert a psd web template to a html template. In that tutorial I found that I couldn't understand a line:

```
body {
    background:#59d3fa url(img/body_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

In this piece of code I don't know what the two zeros `0 0` at the end of the line stand for. I couldn't ask the author of the tutorial this because it was a very old tutorial and the comments were closed. I couldn't find such question on the internet anywhere so I referenced for the background property in w3schools website, but couldn't identify what the zeros at the end stand for. Please, tell me what those mean.

If you think that this is a silly question then please don't complain about me because though I not completely new to CSS, I lack practice.

Comment: read and you are smarter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `0` values represent the position from the left and from the top, respectively, of the document. Think of this as the `position: absolute;` meta-equivalent for the `background` property.

Conveniently, the [Mozilla Developer Network article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) on CSS shorthand uses the `background` property as its example. You can test this in action easily using a **[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ycp0pfhr/)**.

Note that, for non-zero values, you cannot have naked numbers. That is, you must include `%`, `px`, `em`, or `rem`.

Comment: When I changed the `0 0` to `2 2` instead of the background to move slightly it disappeared completely. Why did this happen?

Comment: @TanayKarnik In CSS, typically only values of `0` can exist as naked numbers. There are some exceptions, like the `line-height` property, but you need to use `2px` instead of `2` here (assuming you meant pixels, and not em or rem).

Comment: You need to add % or px to position.